# Program loop bug

Tags: visual-c++

Thanks for reading my problem. My loop code is not working as expected. The console output must not display negative numbers but it still does display them.

```
While (x > 0 && Y > 0)
{ 
 --x; 
 --y; 
 cout << x << endl;
 cout << y << endl; 
}
```

I'm still a beginner in c++.

Comment: I heard its something about clamping that can fix my problem but I don't know what clamping is :(

Comment: Which values are `x` and `y` initialized to? Also `y` is not `Y`.

Comment: Using variable names like this is a very bad idea and *will* get you in trouble like this.  Just not necessary today with text editors that support auto-completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Y' and 'y' are different. Perhaps you want to write it this way:

```
while (x > 0 && y > 0)
{
  // First print the value and then decrement it
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;  
  --x; 
  --y; 

}
```